# Symfony 2 автодополнение после getDoctrine

Tags: php, phpstorm, symfony2, autocomplete

Приветствую. Начал изучать фрэймворк, пишу по-немногу код. Использую phpstorm 9, установил дополнительные плагины, и там идет прекрасное автодополнение.В документации часто встречается такого вида код `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` Вопрос вот в чем, можно ли прописать какую то аннотацию или подключить какой файл, чтобы работало автодополнение после этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант это писать phpDoc непосредственно к переменной

```
/* @var MyService $service */
$service = $this->get('myservice');
```

Далее все методы и поля будут доступны к переменной `$service` в качестве автодополнения.

Comment: в моем случае будет что-то типа /* @var Doctrine $em */, я Вас правильно понял?

Comment: Имя класса туда пишите или тип данных. Далее шторм уже будет адекватно реагировать.